# Apache flink: maintaining message input order in streams with keyBy/connect

Tags: scala, join, stream, apache-flink, rule-engine

## Intro

I am using apache flink to build a rather complex *network* of data streams. The idea is, to implement a *rule engine* with flink.

As a basic description of the application, this is how it is supposed to work:

Data is received by a kafka consumer source, and processed with a number of data streams, until it is finally sent to a kafka producer sink. The incoming data contains objects with a logical key ("object-id"), and the incoming messages *may* refer to the same object-id. For every given object-id, the order of its incoming messages must be retained throughout the application. The order of overall messages can be arbitrary.

This means, messages *a*,*b* and *c* of object1 must be processed in-order, however message *x* of object2 might be processed in between a1/b1/c1, before, or after, it does not matter.

For my current understanding this means I must `keyBy(_.objectID)`, so that messages of the same object are processed in the order they arrived.

## Current approach

To implement the actual *rule engine*, a **network of streams** is created. The idea is the following:

- each rule will have 1-*n* conditions
- for every condition of every rule create a sub-stream of the original stream with `.filter(_.matches(rule.condition))`
- combine all sub-streams which correspond to the same rule by using `substream1.connect(substream2).flatMap(new CombineFunction[MyObject](...))`
- `connect` can only join 2 streams, so a rule with 3 conditions will result in subsequent 2 joins
- rules using the same condition will re-use the same sub-stream created in the second step.

This will result in *n* joined streams, where *n* corresponds to the number of rules. The joined streams will have a `map` function appended to them, which marks the message, so that we know that a rule matched.

Each joined/result stream may publish its result ("rule xyz matched") to the kafka producer independently from the other results, so at this point I can attach the sink to the streams.

## Connect details

Because the `.connect` of two streams ("condition"-substreams) must only pass a message, if it was received on both streams (^= both conditions matched), I need a `RichCoFlatMapFunction` with a keyed state, which can take care of the "pass only if it was received already on the other side".

**However**, the problem is, that the stream is keyed by **object-id**. So what happens if 2 messages of the same object run through the network and reach the `.connect().map(new RichCoFlatMapFunction...)`? It will lead to wrong ouput.
I would need to assign each incoming message a unique ID (UUID) upon entering the network, so I can use this key (instead of the object-id) in the `.connect().map()..` join.
But at the same time, I need the stream to be keyed by object-id, so that messages of the same objects are processed in-order. What to do?

To solve this, I kept the input-stream with `keyBy(_.objectID)`, but the `RichCoFlatMapFunction` in the stream-join no longer uses the keyed-state. Instead, I am using a simple operator state, which keeps a map of passed objects, but implements the same logic, just with manual key/value lookup.

This *seems* to work, however I don't know if this introduces more issues.

## Visualization

The flink GUI will render this image, for a list of 14 rules with a total of 23 conditions (some rules only have one condition):

[image: Network of nodes]
[image]

## Code

The creation of the network is achieved using this code:

```
val streamCache = mutable.Map[Int,DataStream[WorkingMemory]]()
val outputNodesCache = ListBuffer[DataStream[WorkingMemory]]()

if (rules.isEmpty)
  return

// create partial streams for all conditions (first level)
// cache the sub-stream with the hashcode of its condition as key (for re-use)

for (rule <- rules if rule.checks.nonEmpty ;
     cond <- rule.checks if !streamCache.contains(cond.hashCode()))
  streamCache += cond.hashCode -> sourceStream.filter(cond.matches _)

// create joined streams for combined conditions (sub-levels)

for (rule <- rules if rule.checks.nonEmpty)
{
  val ruleName = rule.ruleID

  // for each rule, starting with the rule with the least conditions ...

  if (rule.checks.size == 1)
  {
    // ... create exit node if single-condition rule
    // each exit node applies the rule-name to the objects set of matched rules.

    outputNodesCache += streamCache(rule.checks.head.hashCode).map(obj => { obj.matchedRule = ListBuffer((ruleName, rule.objectType.mkString(":"), rule.statement)) ; obj })
  }
  else
  {
    // ... iterate all conditions, and join nodes into full rule-path (reusing existing intermediate paths)

    var sourceStream:DataStream[WorkingMemory] = streamCache(rule.checks.head.hashCode)
    var idString = rule.checks.head.idString

    for (i <- rule.checks.indices)
    {
      if (i == rule.checks.size-1)
      {
        // reached last condition of rule, create exit-node
        // each exit node applies the rule-name to the objects set of matched rules.

        val rn = ruleName
        val objectType = rule.objectType.mkString(":")
        val statement = rule.statement

        outputNodesCache += sourceStream.map(obj => { obj.matchedRule = ListBuffer((rn, objectType, statement)) ; obj })
      }
      else
      {
        // intermediate condition, create normal intermediate node

        val there = rule.checks(i+1)
        val connectStream = streamCache(there.hashCode)

        idString += (":" + there.idString)

        // try to re-use existing tree-segments

        if (streamCache.contains(idString.hashCode))
          sourceStream = streamCache(idString.hashCode)
        else
          sourceStream = sourceStream.connect(connectStream).flatMap(new StatefulCombineFunction(idString))
      }
    }
  }
}

// connect each output-node to the sink

for (stream <- outputNodesCache)
{
  stream.map(wm => RuleEvent.toXml(wm, wm.matchedRule.headOption)).addSink(sink)
}
```

The `StatefulCombineFunction` used in the previous snippet:

```
class StatefulCombineFunction(id:String) extends RichCoFlatMapFunction[WorkingMemory, WorkingMemory, WorkingMemory] with CheckpointedFunction
{
  @transient
  private var leftState:ListState[(String, WorkingMemory)] = _
  private var rightState:ListState[(String, WorkingMemory)] = _
  private var bufferedLeft = ListBuffer[(String, WorkingMemory)]()
  private var bufferedRight = ListBuffer[(String, WorkingMemory)]()

  override def flatMap1(xmlObject: WorkingMemory, out: Collector[WorkingMemory]): Unit = combine(bufferedLeft, bufferedRight, xmlObject, out, "left")
  override def flatMap2(xmlObject: WorkingMemory, out: Collector[WorkingMemory]): Unit = combine(bufferedRight, bufferedLeft, xmlObject, out, "right")

  def combine(leftState: ListBuffer[(String, WorkingMemory)], rightState: ListBuffer[(String, WorkingMemory)], xmlObject:WorkingMemory, out: Collector[WorkingMemory], side:String): Unit =
  {
    val otherIdx:Int = leftState.indexWhere(_._1 == xmlObject.uuid)

    if (otherIdx > -1)
    {
      out.collect(leftState(otherIdx)._2)
      leftState.remove(otherIdx)
    }
    else
    {
      rightState += ((xmlObject.uuid, xmlObject))
    }
  }

  override def initializeState(context:FunctionInitializationContext): Unit = ???
  override def snapshotState(context:FunctionSnapshotContext):Unit = ???
}
```

I know that clearing of partial-matches out of the operator state is missing (time-to-live), but it is not important for the current state of development, and will be added later.

## Background information

This application shall implement the rete-algorithm for rule matching using flink (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm).

A different approach would be to just loop all rules for every incoming message, and attach the result. I have a working implementation for this approach using flink, so please don't advise this as a solution.

## Issues

The problem is, that the application messes up the order of incoming messages on the object-id level. That is, it does not achieve what I required in the intro. For each object-id, the incoming messages must keep the order. But this is not the case.

I don't know at which point in code the order gets messed up, or how those operations are distributed amongst threads, so I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to keep elements in order in connect operators. But could you introduce more about your application business so that we maybe can figure this out from other perspectives?

Comment: I reworked my initial post to be more detailed/clear. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments...

1. I assume you've checked out Flink's CEP support, in particular [Handling Lateness in Event Time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/cep.html#handling-lateness-in-event-time). The key concept is that you can rely on event time (not processing time) to help with ordering of events, but you always have to decide what's the maximum amount of lateness you're willing to tolerate (and lateness can be caused by both the source, and whatever processing happens in the workflow).
2. From the Flink job graph you provided, it looks like you're partitioning incoming data via hash, but every rule needs to get every incoming data, right? So in that case you need to broadcast.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. to 1): I set the time characteristic of the environment to `IngestionTime`, because the time of event reception will be relevant. That is, from the application point of view, there is no lateness to be handled. But for every incoming message, a message of the same object must not exist the application sooner than the first message.
To 2): Can you elaborate more on this? If I do `.keyBy().filter`, then all messages passing the stream will reach the filter? Or in other words, the filter exists on all partitions of the stream?

Comment: Once you do a `.keyBy()`, you've got a keyed stream. So that means when you do the `.filter()`, you're guaranteed that every record with the same key used for the `keyBy()` will go to the same instance of the `.filter()` operator, but not every record will go to every operator (unless you have a parallelism of 1). See Flink's documentation on broadcast support for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To be honest I fail to find detailed/complete information regarding this, neither the broadcast state documentation nor the keyed stream documentation (which basically doesn't exist) helps. Looking at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/concepts/runtime.html, I don't understand how the partitioning of streams impacts the usage of operators. Do you have a link to documentation regarding this? In my understanding the partitioning is a layer "below" operators, thus partitioning a stream can not "kick out" operators?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "kick out" operators. But once you do a keyBy(), you've got logical groups of records that share the same key. You are guaranteed that all records with the same key will go to the same instance of the operator. If your operator has a parallelism of 1, then obviously all groups (and thus all records) will go to that same (single) instance. But if parallelism is > 1, then groups will be partitioned (sent) to different instances of that operator. HTH.

Comment: Okay but why is this going to be a problem? Unless they randomly go to a different instance of the same operator (which would somehow defeat the purpose of `keyBy`) everything will work out well?

Comment: My original comment was about needing to do a broadcast vs. a keyBy, if every rule needs to "see" every record.